# numpy polynomial TypeError

Tags: python, numpy

I'm using python 3.6.3. I want to call polynomial with list of values but I got a TypeError.

```
Python 3.6.3 (v3.6.3:2c5fed8, Oct  3 2017, 18:11:49) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from numpy.polynomial import Polynomial
>>> p = Polynomial([-3, 2, 0, 1])
>>> p(0)
-3.0
>>> p([1, 2, 3])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Michel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\polynomial\_polybase.py", line 292, in __call__
    arg = off + scl*arg
TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
>>> p([1.0, 2.0, 3.0])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Michel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\polynomial\_polybase.py", line 292, in __call__
    arg = off + scl*arg
TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
>>>
```

I cannot find any related subject on the Net.
Any idea of what missing ?

Comment: *"I want to call polynomial with list of values but I got a TypeError"*. Meaning?.. Do you want to calculate the value of the polynomial **for every** value of the `list`?

Comment: Yes, this is what I want to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given you've got numpy imported, sticking your list of values into an array should not be a problem:

```
>>> p(numpy.array([1, 2, 3]))
array([  0.,   9.,  30.])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can construct Polynomial by passing list of values:

```
f = Polynomial([1, 2, 3])  # means 1 + 2 * x + 3 * x^2
```

You can count value of polynomial by passing number as argument:

```
In [8]: f(1.5)
Out[8]: 10.75
```

However you can't pass list as argument.
If you want to retrieve values for each element of list you should use this code or something similar:

```
In [9]: [f(i) for i in [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]]
Out[9]: [6.0, 17.0, 34.0]
```